# What would be the bottleneck (slowing/blocking operation) of a parallel mymapreduce() implementation ? Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, hadoop, mapreduce

We are learning about mapreduce in Python and I got this question in the test. I was googling for an hour but did not really succeed. 
I am not sure whether I got it correctly:
My insight is that when we launch a pool, mapreduce partition large amount of data and bottleneck could be in reducing all data then. For example, (it was also given as a hint: professor can evaluate tests in parallel but he can't calculate GPA until he finishes the process.

P.S. Sorry if question repeats